# Double search pattern on vb

Tags: vb.net, search

I'm using an array of directories, and a search pattern. Like this

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "ABC*")
```

If I want to search for folders names that start with "ABC" and end with "123" for instance.

How do I include that on the same search pattern, is it possible?

Comment: Please accept an answer instead of changing the title to "(SOLVED)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work.

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "ABC*123")
```

Comment: Well it didn't work out. The folder name length may vary

Comment: @AndréPortugal Why should the length of the foldername matter? According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.110).aspx) the asterisk means `Zero or more characters in that position.`

Comment: I tested with ABCyy123 and ABCyyasdfasdfasfd123 both return with this.

Comment: @AndréPortugal If you care about the length (and know what it should be), then use one or more '?' characters instead of '*'.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "ABC*123")
```